# Cannot run queries in SQLContext from Apache Spark SQL 1.5.2, getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Java application using **Spark SQL** (**Spark 1.5.2** using *local mode*), but I cannot execute any SQL commands without getting errors.

This is the code I am executing:

```
//confs
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();  
sparkConf.set("spark.master","local");
sparkConf.set("spark.app.name","application01");
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.host","10.1.1.36");
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.port", "51810");
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.port", "51815");
sparkConf.set("spark.repl.class.uri","http://10.1.1.36:46146");
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.instances","2");
sparkConf.set("spark.jars","");
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.id","driver");
sparkConf.set("spark.submit.deployMode","client");
sparkConf.set("spark.fileserver.uri","http://10.1.1.36:47314");
sparkConf.set("spark.localProperties.clone","true");
sparkConf.set("spark.app.id","app-45631207172715-0002");

//Initialize contexts
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);           

//execute command
sqlContext.sql("show tables").show();
```

Spark dependencies in **pom.xml** look like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-repl_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class;
```

The **stack trace** is [here](http://pastebin.com/YtnpDLgs).

My application is a web application running on Tomcat 7. I don't have any other configuration files. What could I be doing wrong? Could it be some dependency conflict, since I am able to run the same code in a clean project?

**EDIT**: I found an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8332) that gives some more information about the problem.

Comment: Is com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer already in your class path?

Comment: It is, but when I take off all spark dependencies, I see that I have two jackson jars (probably from another dependency): [jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.12)  and [jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.12). If you access the links, it is possible to see that the packages are moved to **com.fasterxml.jackson.core**, the dependency with conflict. The only choice I got is to track down which maven dependency has this packages and upgrade it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BigDecimalDeserializer wasn't introduced to FasterXML/jackson-module-scala until 2.4](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/commit/3361de9a9779d7a42ed7d5633d9e6bf0bae90d54#diff-d0f3d7dbab9d7250a83e0544f8f00123). Confirm the following:

1. The same jars you compile with are on the classpath at runtime.
2. `${fasterxml.jackson.version}` in the [pom.xml file for Spark SQL](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/sql/core/pom.xml) is 2.4.x or greater.

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
>   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
>   <version>2.4.4</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: Here is a screenshot of [my maven dependency tree](http://imgur.com/i3GCtpK), it seems to be okay, right?

Comment: Are you building this with eclipse?

Comment: I've had problems with class path issues in Eclipse for Spark applications before (actually switched to IntellijIDEA for Spark/Scala applications). Anyways, let me review the dependency hierarchy and see what I can find. Can you try building from the command line and seeing if you get compile errors?

Comment: Here is the [mvn clean install output](http://pastebin.com/WC85y57d), i am not getting any errors

Comment: What happens when you execute this jar? It looks like you have some additional jars on your class path in eclipse.

Comment: When starting tomcat, I got [some errors in the catalina log](http://pastebin.com/Gzs5cS2W) and the error I posted in the question in the [localhost log](http://pastebin.com/r6FWjv64)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97557/discussion-between-myles-baker-and-matheusr).

Comment: The problem was that my project uses an overlay of another project, I just needed to remove manually the conflicted libraries in my project pom, like [this example](http://pastebin.com/j05nCWZL).

Answer (score 5):

In this situation, NoSuchMethodError occurred because of **maven dependency conflict**.

The library which was used by your project during compile time is either not available or some other version of the library is being used during runtime.

I tried many things to solve this conflict issue, and finally following worked for me -

**Just add the correct dependency version of jackson.databind as the first dependency in your pom.xml.**

Use version 2.4.x or greater of jackson.databind dependency.

Note: This will work only for Maven version 2.0.9 and above.

### Why will this work?

In Maven 2.0.9, a new feature of transitive dependencies was added.

> Dependency mediation - this ***determines what version of a dependency will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered***. Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition" which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but ***since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins.***

[Maven Transitive Dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)