# Jackson version issue in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, jackson, jackson-databind

When using `spark structured streaming` with `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11` I was seeing `MethodNotFoundError`'s .  Based on another question [Cannot run queries in SQLContext from Apache Spark SQL 1.5.2, getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184079/cannot-run-queries-in-sqlcontext-from-apache-spark-sql-1-5-2-getting-java-lang)
 I tried to explicitly set the *jackson* version.

Versions 2.9.6, 2.4.3, 2.9.0 have been tried.  The `2.4.3` says "Jackson version too old".   The other versions say

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
   Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.0

Here is the full ST for `2.9.0`:

```
19/05/10 11:30:18 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = dbd581ba-42d7-4496-9fde-fe04dab6e7b4, runId = b5b023df-cb39-4048-90dc-e9a57cce4883] terminated with error
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2783)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at 
 ..
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
   Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.0
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:751)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
```

Note also that I do have exclusions in place in the `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.databind.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
       <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And similar exclusion for AWS

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
       <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Any thoughts on what might fix the jackson versioning issues here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by looking in the $SPARK_HOME/jars directory and searching for `jackson-databind`:

```
$ll *jackson-databind*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 steve  staff  1165323 Mar 26 17:13 jackson-databind-2.6.7.1.jar
```

So then updating the `pom.xml` for

```
    <jackson.databind.version>2.6.7</jackson.databind.version>
```

resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Scala, add in your build.sbt file:

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.7"
```